# Correct way for to use analitic-kit with just a flavor?, putting json file into flavor folder HAPlugin cannot find file

Tags: android, huawei-mobile-services

Two flavors but just i need to use Analitic-kit in:  online flavor (when comment all about analitic-kit can build ),i need rigth way ,(thank you any suggestions)
Trying this

```
app
  /src 
     /main
     /online
         agconnect-services.json
     /offline
```

I get
HAPlugin cannot find "agconnect-services.json" in path: "C:\Users\XL\AndroidStudio\ProjectDemoWithAnalitic\app". Please check the file.*

```
****
dependencies {
        classpath 'com.huawei.agconnect:agcp:1.4.0.300'
        classpath 'com.huawei.hms.plugin:analytics:5.0.1.300'
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Solution:**

Please remove the following code:

```
classpath 'com.huawei.hms.plugin:analytics:5.0.1.300'
apply plugin:'com.huawei.hms.plugin.analytics'
```

**Description:**

Based on the [Analytics Kit Integration Documentation](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/doc/development/HMSCore-Guides-V5/android-integrating-sdk-0000001050161876-V5), the HMS Core SDK integration consists of the following steps:

1. Add the [AppGallery Connect](https://developer.huawei.com/consumer/en/service/josp/agc/index.html) configuration file of the app to your Android Studio project.
2. Add the Maven repository address and Analytics service dependencies in the **build.gradle** file of your project.

   maven {url 'https://developer.huawei.com/repo/'}

   classpath 'com.huawei.hms.plugin:analytics:5.0.1.300'
3. Add the plug-in configuration and SDK version to the **build.gradle** file in the **app** directory.

   apply plugin:'com.huawei.hms.plugin.analytics'

   implementation 'com.huawei.hms:hianalytics:5.0.1.301'
4. Click **Sync Now** or **Sync Project with Gradle Files** to build a project.

The function of the plug-in is to check whether the integration with Analytics is complete. Besides, the plug-in does not support the flavor. Therefore, if you use flavors, you are advised not to use the analytics plug-in.